# Laravel Blade custom directive? looped includes

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade, directive

Let's say I have the following code in my templates

```
@foreach($page->getBannersForPosition('bottom') as $banner)
    @include('partials.'.$banner->type.'.'.$banner->layout)
@endforeach
```

But I would like to have (or something simular, just quick and easy)

```
@banners('bottom')
```

How would I go about doing this in Laravel / Blade?
I found a section on custom directives in the docs but it's not really helping me out much.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you can refer here https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/blade#custom-if-statements

Comment: @ZeroOne that's not even close to my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you move the foreach into its own partial. Then your code could read

```
@include('banners.bottom')
```

Then inside banners.bottom.blade you would have your foreach loop

```
@foreach($page->getBannersForPosition('bottom') as $banner)
    @include('partials.'.$banner->type.'.'.$banner->layout)
@endforeach
```

Comment: That's quite a good idea. I'm gonna give a variable to the include for the position.

Comment: And I end up with @include('banners', ['bannerPosition' => 'bottom'])